# C++ Binary Tree: Return the number of descendants of a node. A leaf has zero. Return -1 if the TreeData is not found

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

Returns the number of descendants of the node storing a character in the tree. A leaf has zero descendants. Return -1 if the TreeData is not found. I have a method that finds the node that we are starting with. If it isn't in the tree it will return -1. Then from that node I need to count the number of descendants and I'm stuck. This is what I have so far.

```
int BSTree::descendants(const TreeData &item) const
{
    Node* foundNode; // pointer to the node we're looking for
    if(!(findNode(item, root, foundNode)))
    {
        return -1; // return -1 if not found
    }
    else
    {
        return descendants(foundNode);
    }
}

int BSTree::descendants(Node *root) const
{
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // Need more here

}

// helper method that finds the node we are looking for to start counting
// descendants from and stores it to foundNode
bool BSTree::findNode(const TreeData &item, Node *root, Node *&foundNode) const
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if(item == *root->item)
    {
        foundNode = root;
        return true;
    }
    else if(item < *root->item)
    {
        findNode(item, root->left, foundNode);
    }
    else
    {
        findNode(item, root->right, foundNode);
    }
}
```

Comment: The next step would be to return the sum of the descendants of the children of the node.

Comment: Your `findNode` is failing to return a value in the recursive cases.

Answer (score 2):

Given a valid node, you need to count both its left and right children (Binary tree):

```cpp
int BSTree::descendants(const Node *root) const
{
    if (!root)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + descendants(root->left) + descendants(root->right);
}
```

Instead of testing if a given Node is a leaf, just test if the pointer you pass is `NULL` or not (on that matter, why `NULL` if you write C++? Prefer `nullptr` if you can use C++11 or higher). This will automatically handle the case of a leaf since both `descendants(root->left)` and `descendants(root->right)` will return 0.

**Note: The function will actually return the number of descendants + 1 in the end**

Comment: Thanks! Awesome. Don't I have to at least return 1 somewhere? I only see a case where you return 0 for NULL but when you're adding up the descendants don't you need a case where it'll return 1?

Comment: @Bapho: Whoops you're right, I missed that. Fixed :)